# Hangman game is broken

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make this hangman game but it won't work. Does anyone have any suggestions to fix it?

```
import random, os

print("^^^^^^^^^^THIS IS HANGMAN^^^^^^^^^^")
print("1. Play Game ")
print("2. Quit Game ")
choice = input("Please enter option 1 or 2")

if choice == "1":

    words = ["handkerchief", "accommodate", "indict", "impetuous"]
    word = random.choice(words)
    guess = ['_'] * len(word)
    guesses = 7

    while '_' in guess and guesses > 0:
        print(' '.join(guess))
        character = input('Enter character: ')

        if len(character) > 1:
            print('Only enter one character.')
            continue

        if character not in word:
            guesses -= 1

        if guesses == 0:
            print('You LOST!')
            break

        else:
            print('You have only', guesses, 'chances left to win.')

    else:
        print(''.join(guess))
        print('You WON, well done')
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Also note that [tag:python-requests] is for a specific library, not just because you're requesting someone fix your code.

Comment: Quick look: `if len(character) > 1:` and `if character not in word:` needs to be intended within the while loop

Comment: "Broken" is what way?

Comment: @finefoot: I was trying to point out to the OP why their question doesn't fit the site's guidelines for being a [mcve]. Folks trying to help shouldn't have to run the code in a question to figure-out what the question means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, when you say the game doesn't work - you mean that the correctly guessed characters don't appear? That's because you don't change your `guess` variable. It will always only contain `_` characters if you don't update it every time:

```
for i, c in enumerate(word):
    if c == character:
        guess[i] = character
```

---

So if you add that to your code (nothing else changed), the complete game looks like this:

```
import random, os

print("^^^^^^^^^^THIS IS HANGMAN^^^^^^^^^^")
print("1. Play Game ")
print("2. Quit Game ")
choice = input("Please enter option 1 or 2")

if choice == "1":

    words = ["handkerchief", "accommodate", "indict", "impetuous"]
    word = random.choice(words)
    guess = ['_'] * len(word)
    guesses = 7

    while '_' in guess and guesses > 0:
        print(' '.join(guess))
        character = input('Enter character: ')

        if len(character) > 1:
            print('Only enter one character.')
            continue

        if character not in word:
            guesses -= 1

        for i, c in enumerate(word):
            if c == character:
                guess[i] = character

        if guesses == 0:
            print('You LOST!')
            break

        else:
            print('You have only', guesses, 'chances left to win.')

    else:
        print(''.join(guess))
        print('You WON, well done')
```

---

I have changed the structure a little bit to make the code more intuitive in my eyes:

```
import random

WORDS = ["handkerchief", "accommodate", "indict", "impetuous"]
MAX_GUESSES = 7

print("^^^^^^^^^^THIS IS HANGMAN^^^^^^^^^^")

while True:

    input('Press <ENTER> to start a new game or <CTRL>+<C> to quit.')

    word = random.choice(WORDS)
    guess = ['_'] * len(word)
    guesses = set()
    n = MAX_GUESSES

    while True:

        print('\nYour word:', ' '.join(guess))
        print('You have {} chances left.'.format(n))

        if '_' not in guess:
            print('Congratulations, you win!\n')
            break

        if n < 1:
            print('Sorry, no guesses left. You lose!\n')
            break

        character = input('Guess a new character: ')

        if len(character) != 1:
            print('You must enter exactly one character!')
            continue

        if character in guesses:
            print('You have already guessed that character!')
            continue

        guesses.add(character)

        if character not in word:
            n -= 1
            continue

        for i, c in enumerate(word):
            if c == character:
                guess[i] = character
```

Comment: do you know how to add a function which says you have already used that letter pick a different one?

Comment: Do you know how to clear the screen after each game has ended and reset to the menu

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make hangman games. For reference, here's what I did:

```py
import random
from english_words import english_words_set

five_letter_words = [word for word in english_words_set if len(word) == 5]
words_list = list(five_letter_words)
word = random.choice(words_list)
print("I have a word. You have 12 tries to guess it.")
hang_count = 0
inputs_list = []
correct_list = ['_'] * len(word)


def check_duplicates(letter):
   return letter in inputs_list


while hang_count < 12 and '_' in correct_list:
   letter_input = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()


   if check_duplicates(letter_input):
       print(f'You cannot guess "{letter_input}" again')
       continue
   inputs_list.append(letter_input)


   if letter_input in word:
       for index, letter in enumerate(word):
           if letter == letter_input:
               correct_list[index] = letter_input
       print(f"Correct! Current word: {''.join(correct_list)}")
   else:
       hang_count += 1
       print(f"Incorrect. You have {(12 - hang_count)} guesses left!")
       print(f"Current word: {''.join(correct_list)}")




if hang_count == 12:
   print(f"The word was {word}.")
   print("Your Hangman Died!")
else:
   print(f"The word was {word}.")
   print("Your Hangman Lived!")
```

It does use an English words set that has many words that are quite complicated, so for the words list, you may want to try something else.